# How to disable a route or permalink in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

In my wordpress dashboard I've got a link called "che passa". When I click on it, I can create articles and the route will be for example => "www.website.com/che-passa/test"
I need to **disable** the link "che-passa" and I really don't know how to do it. Are there any wordpress developpers here ?

Comment: Is 'che passa' a custom post type? You can add `'has_archive' -> false` to the post type registration if so.

Answer (score 0):

I found the archive.php and I deleted all the code and replace it by =>
`wp_redirect(home_url("")); exit();` And it work :)